# Problems with BFW Server (firewall) files

Tags: firewall, linux

Hi everyone in server **fault**

I will try to be more specific I can, cause it is not a kind of usual question.

**Intro:**

I work with a firewall called BFW (Brazil Firewall). It's the old software called **"Coyote"** is a kind of minimalist distro of linux. It is mainly used to control ISP company.

**Now about the problem**

I have a php system based (ERP Like), and I'm trying i kind of integration with the BFW server. 
The problem rely on 2 files, the files are called subnet.cfg and firewall.
The subnet.cfg stores information about the contracts, customers and plans. A file is generated and imported with wget command from the BFW. My php system generated this file, every 30 minutes and put the file in BFW server. The BFW server reload itself also every 30 minutes, then the file is always updated since it come from the php system.

Until here everything is done wonderfully well. But I think the BFW has a bug because it crashs itself, after a subnet reload.

**Some more details about the BFW**

The BFW has 2 files with the same name, these files are: `/etc/coyote/subnet.cfg` and `/mnt/config/subnet.cfg`

The `/etc/coyote/subnet.cfg` file is the physical file and the `/mnt/config/subnet.cfg` is in memory executing.

The file is loaded to memory and still there until the **subnet.reload** command is triggered.
But when the command reload is called everything mess up and the BFW go down, the file **subnet.cfg** is corrupted and then, need to re-install some files on the server.

**My question here is:**

What do I need to do in such a situation? 
At a first sight it was a simply task, but now it change into a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the link (Bad Quality). Now the solution above is working wonderfully.